# Trouble Transforming IEEE 754 data to be displayed in PyQt4

Tags: python, numpy, pyqt4, ieee-754

I have a large image stored in an nparry with each pixel IEEE 754 formatted. I am trying to view the image in PyQt4.  I have tried using QImage and QPixmap with the available formats but have been unable to view the image properly.  I am hoping there is a module that transforms IEEE 754 data to a format that PyQt4 is able to display.

Comment: You can provide the image you have in zip through dropbox, drive or similar.

Comment: @eyllanesc: I don't agree with putting the image on dropbox or other external sites. In a few months or years those links will become stale and future readers won't be able to understand the issue. For this reason Stack Overflow posts should be stand-alone and contain all necessary info. Jim please make an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that includes a numpy array with synthetic test data. Also please elaborate on what you mean with *"unable to view the image properly"*. Perhaps a screen shot will make it clear.

Comment: @titusjan I understand what you are saying, my intention is for the user to share the file and I would try to display it properly in your post since I have enough reputation to edit your question. :P

Comment: Thank you both for the responses.  I will get you guys some more to work with.